# Pass parameters to chained responses with rxjava+retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a list of objects that have id, name and url and i need to call service to get image url for each element in that list but i also need to add that url to each object, something like this

```
public class PhotoDomainEntity {
String id;
String name;
String urL;}
```

Id and name are known but i need to call rest service to get url like this

```
 Observable.from(entities)
                    .flatMap(new Func1<PhotoDomainEntity, Observable<PhotoEntity>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<PhotoEntity> call(PhotoDomainEntity s) {
                            //call get photo details for each id

                            return PhotosApi.photosApi.getPhotoData(Constants.API_KEY, s.id,
                                    Constants.FLICKR_FORMAT, Constants.NO_JSONP_RESPONSE);
                        }
                    })
```

For each call i need to add url to the PhotoDomainEntity. How can i pass the id, and name when response arrives for each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Observable.from(entities)
.flatMap(new Func1<PhotoDomainEntity, Observable<PhotoEntity>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<PhotoEntity> call(final PhotoDomainEntity s) {
        //call get photo details for each id

        return PhotosApi.photosApi.getPhotoData(
            Constants.API_KEY,
            s.id,
            Constants.FLICKR_FORMAT,
            Constants.NO_JSONP_RESPONSE)
        .map(new Func1<PhotoEntity, PhotoEntity>() {

            @Override
            public PhotoEntity call(PhotoEntity fromServer) {
                // if mutable:
                fromServer.setId(s.getId());

                return fromServer;
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: this helped alot tnx :)